# All-in-one GNSS localization solution (hardware+software)

Tags: localization, software, gps, gnss, hardware

Is there something like an all-in-one satellite based localization solution that would contain both hardware and software to do GNSS localization for robotics? I mean a package that would also contain an IMU, would fuse it with GPS and filter the result accordingly and then provide a software API to query for location/speed etc.

I am interested rather in some affordable solution but is there some professional hardware too?

I am trying to implement this for my mobile robot and I realize that a smartphone-grade GPS (Samsung J5) gives me better preliminary results than an u-blox eval board ([this NEO-M8T](http://www.csgshop.com/product.php?id_product=221) with integrated antenna and ground plane) - I wonder why, I guess Android may fuse the IMU and have better readings even with worse antenna?

Comment: I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 2):

I have used both KVH CNS-5000 and the Xsens MTi-G-710 that do what you are asking. Both these products provide on-board sensor fusion. The CNS-5000 uses an EKF and I am not sure about the Xsens. They both cost in excess of $4k. I am unaware of any less costly solutions that integrate both the GNSS and IMU.